# SSH new file/directory group write permission different than FTP etc

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, sftp, sshfs

I am a non-root user on our Linux (Debian) install, and the file/folder permissions on the existing files in my home folder are -rw-rw-r-- and drwxrwxr-x for directories, and if I log into SSH directly (I use putty on Windows 7), then create a new file or folder, it creates it with those permissions. However, if I log in any other way, such as with FTP or SFTP or with my file editor (like Eclipse or Sublime Text) or with anything else, like win-sshfs, any file or folder I create doesn't have group write permission.

I've already added umask 002 to my .bash_profile, logged out of everything and back in, but no dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This behavior is FTP-/SFTP-server specific. You did not specify what server you are using.*

*For SFTP, I'm assuming OpenSSH, as that's used by a majority of distributions. For FTP, I'm making no guesses.*

---

The OpenSSH SFTP server does not follow an umask you set in `.bash_profile`. Instead it uses it's own umask setting. It's a global setting by default. While it can be set per user, it can be set by a root only (it's configured in the `sshd_config`).

For more details see [SFTP-server uploaded files having wrong rights](https://serverfault.com/q/645150/168875).

---

An alternative solution (as also suggested in the link above), is to use an SFTP client that allows specifying permissions for uploaded files.

For example WinSCP allows that.

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom

[image: Setting permissions for uploaded files in WinSCP]

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: We're using Debian but they just don't have the group write permissions masked properly through SFTP, and FileZilla doesn't let me set a mask, so I'll just use WinSCP.